# How do you turn off quote matching in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How do you turn off automatic matching of single and double quotes in Visual Studio 2015? I'm taking about the behavior where you type the character and then nothing visible happens until you type it a second time.

I know the feature is for writing fresh code, but it forces you into three keystrokes just to insert a character and drives me crazy coming from vim.

I have "Automatic Brace Completion" turned off.

Update: It seems this might be a system-wide problem; I'm seeing it here in SO edit windows too...

Comment: What language in particular are you using with studio? Any add-ins?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > [Language, e.g. C#].
Then uncheck **Automatic brace completion**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Nikolai, but I had already seen that in other responses and turned off automatic brace completion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me turned out to be that I was using an International English keyboard layout, so it was trapping the single and double quote characters for typing accents on characters for European languages.